# TI Nspire CAS Implicit Differentiation not returning correct result (returning 0)

Tags: implicit-differentiation, calculator

Taking the derivative of $y^3-xy=2$, the correct result should be $y'=y/(3y^2-x)$.

However, when I use the impDif() function on TI Nspire CAS, the returned result is 0, as shown in the screenshot below.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAMj3.png)

OS Version: 5.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem. It's just an interpretation issue with the CAS feature. It interpreted $xy$ as one variable named $xy$ instead of $x*y$. Solved when a multiplication sign is used in between x and y.

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guwVU.png)